# Can't remove wine 1.4 rc5

Tags: wine

I installed **Wine 1.4 rc5**. Later I realised that this wine won't work because there is no sound. I removed it using **Synaptic Package Manager** and installed **Wine 1.2** which is the stable version of **Ubuntu 10.04**. Even though I install it. It's still showing **Wine 1.4 rc-5**. How can I remove **wine 1.4-rc5** and install **Wine 1.2** ?

Comment: Can you give the output of `dpkg -l wine*`?

Comment: @Anwar                              Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  winetricks     0.0+20120308~p Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (winet
No packages found matching wine-1.4-rc5.tar.bz2.ug_.

Comment: Check the answer whether if helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed **Wine 1.4 rc5** by compiling the source code and was compiled in a directory under Home.

I found this and on the compiled Wine directory, I ran this :

> sudo make
>
> sudo make uninstall

When I did the command, the compiled version was uninstalled successfully. I was able to install **Wine 1.2** after I uninstalled the compiled program.

So the solution is check for other Wine compiled versions and uninstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Your output in the comment showing that, you have winetricks installed. Use this command to remove the wine completely.

```
sudo apt-get --auto-remove purge winetricks
```

Hope this will work